# Using a JavaScript Package with TypeScript Typings in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the Twitter Lite library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-lite) in an SPA that's implemented with Angular 9. Twitter Lite is a JavaScript library that includes typings for TypeScript support.

As per the example given in the typings (https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite/blob/master/index.d.ts) I import the main class in one of the components (let's call it TwitterComponent):

```
import { Twitter } from 'twitter-lite';
```

And then use the class in the component:

```
const twitter = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'XYZ',
    consumer_secret: 'XYZ',
    access_token_key: 'XYZ',
    access_token_secret: 'XYZ'
});
```

The code compiles fine but navigating to any of the components that are under the module that TwitterComponent belongs to results in this error:

**Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined**

What's the right way to use a JS library like this, with TS support? Should the module import something? Or is this error more likely to be related to the way Twitter Lite itself is implemented?

In case you'd suggest to import the library like this:

```
import * as Twitter from 'twitter-lite';
```

It gives this compile-time error for the code initiating the class:

**This expression is not constructable. Type 'typeof TwitterLite' has no construct signatures.**

Which is strange on its own since the class does have a constructor defined.

Comment: lt is because the namespace is exported and not the class.

Comment: Can I edit the typings to export the class myself?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to waste time with editing this file. Did you try to update you package to the latest version (v0.10.1-0)? It includes the resolution of your problem.

Comment: That's the version I'm using already. Never used a previous version

Answer (score 0):

There are an issue with the release you use from this library. This is a known issue and the resolution is coming. Meanwhile according to this [thread on Github](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite/pull/88), you should apply the following changes to your code:

```
import Twitter = require('twitter-lite');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that thread on Github. I tried what you suggested as well as other suggestions on that thread (it has progressed since your answer), including "const Twitter = require('twitter-lite')". Still getting the same error